# Multiple test folders in module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, automated-tests

I have setup my Android project with Gradle 2.2.1, which contains one module.
This has a folder named "androidTest" where I'm placing the tests. This is standard in the Android plugin for Gradle and it works.

Now, I would like to have two different test suites for the same project, each one of them located in a different directory.

Is this possible?

I was thinking of creating two different tasks "extending" connectedAndroidTest, and each one overwriting the folder of the tests...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A little old, but it was the first result when I was searching!

So this is fairly easy, you can just add each folder to the source sets:

```
android {
...
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.resources.srcDirs += 'src/newAndroidTest/resources'
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/newAndroidTest/java'
    }
}
```

These folders should now be included with the current src/androidTest folders when you run them.

Comment: If you just make a `newAndroidTest` Java source set, it should pick up `src/<set>/resources` and `src/<set>/java` automatically

Comment: Then would it be processed when you run connectedAndroidTests though? I would have thought you'd have to manually wire up everything that way... (which I guess, might be what you want!)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `connectAndroidTests`. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout